# Trouble creating a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

The problem I have is to create a procedure called `prc_cus_balance_update` that will take the invoice number as a parameter and update the customer balance (hint you can use the declare section to define a totinv number variable that holds the computed invoice total)

So far I have

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PRC_CUS_BALANCE_UPDATE]
   (@INVID INT)
AS
   DECLARE @INVTOT INT
   DECLARE @CUSID INT

   BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     SELECT CUS_CODE INTO CUSID
     FROM INVOICE
     WHERE INVOICE.INV_NUMBER = @INVID

     IF CUSID > 0 
        UPDATE CUSTOMER
        SET CUS_BALANCE = CUS_BALANCE +
                          (SELECT INV_TOTAL
                           FROM INVOICE
                           WHERE INV_NUMBER = INVID)
        WHERE CUS_CODE = CUSID
     END IF
   END
```

But every time I try to compile it it gives me an incorrect syntax near keyword END. I have found similar post online but i always end up with the same error.

Comment: What database engine are you using? (SQL Server, MySql etc)

Comment: sql server, sorry should have included that

Answer (score 4):

In Transact-SQL, which your SP appears to be written in, the syntax of [`IF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx) is this:

```
IF Boolean_expression 
     { sql_statement | statement_block } 
[ ELSE 
     { sql_statement | statement_block } ]
```

As you can see, there's no closing `END IF`. So, one solution is simply to remove the `END IF`, in which case your `IF` statement would be simply

```
IF CUSID > 0 
    UPDATE CUSTOMER
    SET CUS_BALANCE = CUS_BALANCE +
        (SELECT INV_TOTAL
         FROM INVOICE
         WHERE INV_NUMBER = INVID)
    WHERE CUS_CODE = CUSID
;
```

If you want your `IF` statement to end with an `END`, enclose the body into a `BEGIN…END` block:

```
IF CUSID > 0 
BEGIN
    UPDATE CUSTOMER
    SET CUS_BALANCE = CUS_BALANCE +
        (SELECT INV_TOTAL
         FROM INVOICE
         WHERE INV_NUMBER = INVID)
    WHERE CUS_CODE = CUSID;
END;
```

There are other issues too. It seems some references to the variables `@CUSID` and `@INVTOT` do not start with the `@` character. Also, you seem to be using `SELECT INTO` to assign a value to a variable. (Are you converting this SP from MySQL?)

To address those issues:

1. In Transact-SQL, variable names always start with the `@` character, whether in declarations or in references.
2. To assign a value to a variable, use the following syntax:

   ```
   SELECT @varname = ...
   [ FROM ...
   WHERE ... ]
   ```

   So, in your case, the SELECT statement should probably be this:

   ```
   SELECT @CUSID = CUS_CODE
   FROM INVOICE
   WHERE INVOICE.INV_NUMBER = @INVID
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some other problems as well:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PRC_CUS_BALANCE_UPDATE]  --<<<<use CREATE to create !
   (@INVID INT)
AS
   DECLARE @INVTOT INT  --<<<<<<what is the point of this variable as it is not used?
   DECLARE @CUSID INT

   BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     /*<<<<if the following is only testing for the existence within INVOICE table then<<< 
     SELECT CUS_CODE 
     INTO CUSID
     FROM INVOICE
     WHERE INVOICE.INV_NUMBER = @INVID

     IF CUSID > 0 
     <<<<replace with following<<<<<*/
     IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INVOICE WHERE INVOICE.INV_NUMBER = @INVID)   

        BEGIN  --<<<<<as already mentioned
        UPDATE CUSTOMER
        SET CUS_BALANCE = CUS_BALANCE +
                          (SELECT INV_TOTAL
                           FROM INVOICE
                           WHERE INV_NUMBER = INVID) --<<<is this supposed to be =@INVID ?
        WHERE CUS_CODE = CUSID  --<<<this looks odd as it seems you are trying to say "CUS_CODE = <some table created earlier>" ?
        END;  --<<<<<as already mentioned
     END IF
   END
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer it occurred to me to take a closer look at the rest of the SP. The SELECT statement is probably needed, please see my update.

Comment: If you create a _table_ called `CUSID` and then later try to do `WHERE CUS_CODE = CUSID` then I believe it will throw an error

Comment: My point was that the SELECT INTO syntax was meant as something else. All the issues that are there (`END IF`, seemingly unnecessary `SELECT INTO name`, odd conditions) suggest to me that this was originally a MySQL procedure.

Comment: And no, `WHERE CUS_CODE = CUSID` won't throw an error simply because there's a table called `CUSID`. It will throw an error if there's no column called `CUSID`. But again, I think the `CUSID` is meant to be a variable, which in MySQL can be referenced without the `@`.

Comment: currently I have no knowledge of MySQL so can't really help ! SQL-Server you might do `SELECT INTO #CUSID` to place into a temp table

Comment: I thought i had it figured out when it compiled successfully but then when i go to the customer table it didn't affect anything.